# String substitution in Python with brackets

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution

I'm trying to replace some words in a string with another word, but involve brackets. So for example:

Seeking to replace `MyFunction()` with `MyOtherFunction{}`

Sample input:

```
This is MyFunction(argument1(something))
```

Desired output:

```
This is MyOtherFunction{argument(something)}
```

I would like the solution to be work with multiple items contained within the bracket. So it should still work for `MyFunction(argument1(something), argument2(something else))`. I tried using `regex` on nongreedy wildcard, but the problem is the `)` contained with the argument. Is there another way to do this involving `regex`?

Comment: You need to use a parser, not regex alone.

Comment: Would you recommend argparse or some alternative?

Comment: `argparse` is for parsing the command line and associating actions with it. You need to make yourself familiar with the basic theory of programming language parsing (Chomsky hiearchy) in order to make sure that you're not trying to solve an unsolvable problem. And then you should implement your own parser or figure out [Yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) depending on the complexity of the problem and your available time. Do you want to replace the outer `(` with `{`?

Comment: Yes, trying to replace the outer () with {}. Thanks for your reponse.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Unfortunately, this platform is not well-suited to brainstorming, and so these kinds of questions are off-topic. To get an answerable question, you first need to start working on actual code, and keep going until you get stuck. I would recommend running `help("str")` in python, to get more information about what Python supports natively.